# Having an issue with fwrite in PHP - What's wrong with my code?

Tags: php, forms, fwrite

I'm getting the error "*Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/dir/public_html/admin/edit.php on line 6*"

I'm trying to write to a file with a form.  I also was wondering how to put the current form contents into the text area.

```
<?php

$ourFileName = $_GET['page'];
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_POST['stuff'];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($ourFileHandle);

?>

<form action="edit.php?page=index.txt" method="post">
<textarea name="stuff" rows="10" cols="50" wrap="virtual" maxlength="300"></textarea>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is just sample code but you might want to be careful w/using the $_GET['page'] variable to explicitly specify the file path to write to w/out any sort of filtering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your file handler variable in `fwrite()`:

```
fwrite($ourFileHandle, $stringData);
```